# Bounding a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, trigonometry

Defining $f(x):=\sin(nx/2)/(n\cdot\sin(x/2))$ where $n$ is odd and positive, defining $x_k:=2\pi k/n$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and focusing on $x\in[0,\pi/n]$, I would like to find a bound for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(x-x_k)|$.

I've been able to re-write $f(x-x_k)$ using exponentials, but taking the norm of that expression only gives me that $|f(x-x_k)|\leq1$ which tells me that my above sum is bounded by $n$. While this is indeed a bound, I've been told that there is a much better bound: $1+\sum_m^{n-1}(1/(2m-1))$. I would like to show this bound, but am unsure how to start. If there are any hints or suggestions (or proofs) out there, I would gladly welcome them. Thank you in advance!